# Code snippet for reading float values from a file and set them into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Someone gave to me a code snippet to load float values from an ASCII file (here Positions.dat) and to set these values into an array. This code uses jQuery:

```
 $.get("/Positions.dat", function(content) {
      var array = content.split(/\n/).filter(function(line) {
      return line.trim().length > 0;
    }).map(function(line) {
      return line.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function(word) {
        return +parseFloat(word);
      });
    });

  console.log(array);
  alert(array);

  });
```

The file `Positions.dat` is on server side and contains 3 columns of float values.

I am not a Javascript expert and I would like to understand better this code snippet.

I think it firstly split all the lines with `'\n' delimiter`, then only select the lines with `a number of elements > 0 per line` (select only non-empty lines with `trim`), then for each line split the 3 words and convert each one to float.

The syntax is quite complex for me, anyone could give more precisions on the nested functions used ( `map` for `line` and `word`) ?

Secondly, I try to include this code into another script to put array values into another array :

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $.get("/Positions.dat", function(content) {
          var array = content.split(/\n/).filter(function(line) {
          return line.trim().length > 0;
        }).map(function(line) {
          return line.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function(word) {
            return +parseFloat(word);
          });
        });
      });

   for(var p = 0; p < 10; p++) {

                var pX = array[p*3];
                var pY = array[p*3+1];
                var pZ = array[p*3+2];
    }  

</script>
```

But I get the following error on console :

```
ReferenceError: array is not defined
```

Maybe array is a `local variable` above, so I try to put it `global` but I get the same error.

What can I try next?

Comment: Related to (probably duplicate of) [Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086) or [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not used to the "asynchronous" logic in javascript ...